# Can not login user SEC_MGR in SQLPLUS

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I can login user SEC_MGR when I use the TOAD tool. But, It has error when i login by SQLPLUS:

[image]

[image]

Comment: remove the 'as SYSDBA' on your connect string, does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this version I am using is Oracle 12c, so user SEC_MGR is replaced by SYSTEM user.

Try to login with user SYSTEM/manager to access.

Comment: `SYSTEM` does not have the sysdba privilege and thus you can't logon with `SYSTEM` and `as sysdba`